# Is it possible to alter normal column to virtual column in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, ddl, virtual-columns

```
ALTER TABLE TAB_NAME ADD TEST_COL VARCHAR2(255);
ALTER TABLE TAB_NAME MODIFY TEST_COL GENERATED ALWAYS as ('some_exp') VIRTUAL;
```

Second script gives an error:

```
Error report -
ORA-54026: Real column cannot have an expression
54026. 0000 -  "Real column cannot have an expression"
*Cause:    Attempted to alter a real column to have an expression.
*Action:   This is not valid, change the DDL.
```

Comment: To alter - no. Drop and re-create - yes. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7ea8b19c238fa24815c2fe2152e9a372)

Comment: Okay..Thanks Akina.